# How can I configure myhostname to work with postfix and Ubuntu 14.04 on Azure VM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, postfix

My hostname file reads as this.

```
virtual-machine-set
```

hostname -f

```
virtual-machine-set
```

/etc/hosts reads like this

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
191.xxx.xx.xx myazuredomain.cloudapp.net

#The following are name resolutions for INCRONTAB sync
myusername@myazuredomain.cloudapp.net:22 virtual-machine-set
myusername@myazuredomain.cloudapp.net:23 virtual-machine-set-2

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
127.0.0.1 virtual-machine-set # bitnami-hosts-patch
```

my postfix/main.cf reads like this

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated         defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mydesireddomain.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mydesireddomain.com, virtual-machine-set, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
```

my /etc/mailname is as such

```
mydesireddomain.com
```

As a result of this I am getting mail that is coming in as " Ubuntu bitnami@virtual-machine-set "

The myhostname which I want for using mail being sent so that it reflects the name of my domain is not being utilized at all.

I will note but I am assuming this is not the problem is that I don't have an MX recored setup as of yet for mydesireddomain.com dns.  I don't think that has anything to do with the issue though.

Comment: Why do people vote down a question?  You cant help instead.

Comment: i find it absolutely ridiculous that someone would just down vote without proving any response.

Comment: When you hoover your mouse pointer over the down-vote button the reason appears *"this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"*

Answer (score 2):

You emails are sent with what you have configured in your hosts file, the result of the hostname command. Nothing wrong there.